# Where is located mysqlpump log file in Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: aws

I am neither a DB administrator, nor a DevOps but I need to migrate a very large table (~500M rows) from one MySQL schema to another. For doing so, I use `mysqlpump`backup tool. Also, since the DB is an AWS DB, I establish an SSH connection to the Ubuntu server from terminal and then run the command from command line.

Everything works as needed and I can see the process being output on my terminal, but once my computer sleeps or I have an internet connection interruption, I am facing a problem: `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe`.

That's probably ok, but after reconnection to the Ubuntu server I don't see that process output on the terminal, nor I can see the corresponding process in the processes list.

I don't know if that can be, but once my terminal looses the connection with the server mysqlpump terminates on the server without completion.

In order to be sure, I would like to know:

- if that can happen or no?
- Where mysqlpump logs its process so I could take a look at the log file and see what happened?

Comment: Have you looked at the manpages? Run `man mysqlpump`

Comment: There's an option to specify a log file: `--log-error-file=file_name Log warnings and errors by appending them to the named file. If this option is not given, mysqlpump writes warnings and errors to the standard error output.`.   But as it is said, only warnings and errors can be logged. What about the standard info output?

Comment: I also found this: --result-file=file_name Direct output to the named file. The result file is created and its previous contents overwritten, even if an error occurs while generating the dump. I'll try it.

Comment: Could you consider reinstalling MySQLPump? It's kind of a universal answer for everything, and it solves almost everything...